# How to keep a link to a folder after restart?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, partitioning

I created a link to a folder of another partition in my computer and then restarted it. When Ubuntu started, my folder link has turned into a plain document and when I try to open it, it says: "The link to (my folder name) is broken..." or something. Does anybody know how to make a link properly in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem in the past. The reason is after you restart Ubuntu, it doesn't mount all the partitions automatically.

So in order to use the link you created you will have to mount the corresponding partition first.

The image below shows the Nautilus opened just after restarting Ubuntu. As you can see I have marked two partitions I have on my system. They are not mounted yet. So now if I click on any link which is inside these partitions then it will not open.

[image: Partitions]

This is what you might be seeing.

[image: Error]

So, the only thing you have to do is mount the partition before clicking on the link.

As you can see in the image below, I have mounted the corresponding partition and the link has returned to normal from the plain document.

[image: Mounted]